# In my configurations to setup IIS, SQL-Server, & ASP.NET below, are there unnecessary settings leading to security issues?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7.5

I am learning ASP.NET MVC 3 from many sources on the internet. I am worrying whether my settings based on the mixed information contains unnecessary things leading to security risks.

In this topic, I need your suggestion or comment pertaining to my settings explained below. I will assign a number to each step to make it easier to be referenced in your comment or suggestion.

---

**STEP 1: Enabling IIS**

[image]

---

**STEP 2: Installing .NET 4**

No image :-)

---

**STEP 3: Installing SQL-Server 2008R2**

No image :-)

---

**STEP 4: Installing Visual Studio 2010**

No image :-)

---

**STEP 5: Make a project, e.g., NerdDinner**

I put my project file (including NerdDinner.mdb) under C:\

NerdDinner.mdb is already populated with dummy data.

[image]

---

**STEP 6: Configuring Global Application Pool**

[image]

---

**STEP 7: Make Virtual Directory using Visual Studio 2010**

[image]

Shown in IIS Manager, NerdDinner is an application under the default web site.

[image]

---

**STEP 8: Configuring Application Pool for NerdDinner web app**

[image]

---

**STEP 9: Attaching and Configuring NerdDinner.mdb using Sql-Server Management Studio**

[image]

---

**STEP 10: Configuring Connection String**

```
 <add name="NerdDinnerEntities"   

  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NerdDinner.csdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.ssdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
     Data Source=.\sqlexpress;
     Initial Catalog=NerdDinner;
     Integrated Security=True;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True
     &quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

---

**Testing**

Everything works well, but I am not sure whether or not these steps contains security issues.

Comment: oh, nobody gives comment or suggestion. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a production environment tip, but you should practice it on your development machine as well.

IIS7.x by default will create a separate application pool for your website named after the name you give the website.

Instead of running the application pool and the site/application under `NETWORK SERVICE`, run both the site and the pool as `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

In the website or application features pane open the Authentication feature select *Anonymous Authentication* and do right-click Edit:

[image]

Next, ensure your website is running in its own application pool. Sub applications may benefit from their own application pool, but we tend to put them in the same pool as the parent site unless there is a need for a different runtime configuration such as a different version of ASP.NET or Pipeline mode.

[image]

When you have configured this grant the requisite permissions to the pool identity on your web folders by doing:

`ICACLS c:\dynamic\NerdDinner\NerdDinner /grant "IIS AppPool\site1":(CI)(OI)(M)`

Or you can apply these permissions via explorer:
[image]

Click `Check Names` then `OK`:
[image]

In SQL Server the same thing applies, instead of giving permissions on your database to NETWORK SERVICE, give permissions to the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` instead. As with `NETWORK SERVICE` this will only work if the SQL database is on the same machine as the web server if you're running a standalone server.

For example:
[image]

In the dialogue shown above, don't search and `Check Names` because this will replace the `IIS AppPool\` portion of the username with your machine name. When you click OK SQL will complain that it can't locate `[MACHINENAME]\NerdDinner`.

Next set the add as a login to the NerdDinner database:
[image]

I'm setting as DB Owner here but you can choose the role you see fit for your needs. If this is your development machine then DBO will be fine because you can then do DDL from within Visual Studio. Most shared host production environments will make the first login (which is usually all you get) DBO anyway because many apps such as DotNetNuke etc need full control over their databases.

The connection string you've provided in your example should work as-is without any changes.

For more information on this topic:

> [Application Pool Identities (IIS.NET)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)
>   [New in IIS 7 - App Pool Isolation (Ken Schaefer)](http://adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2008/01/29/15759.aspx)

Comment: @Kev, thank you for your nice looking answer. I am sorry for commenting late since I am formatting my whole system. I will come back soon to make a comment for your answer.

Comment: @Kev, where is the best place to store my database NerdDinner.mdf if my SQL server instance runs on a computer on which IIS also runs? If I put it inside the physical directory of the site/app, does it open a security risk?

Comment: @xport - If you do that you should store them in `/App_Data`. In practice ASP.NET should prevent HTTP access to the `App_Data` special folder. On top of that there's an ASP.NET `HttpForbiddenHandler` mapped to `.ldf` and `.mdf` files (SQL data and logs) which will prevent downloading of these file types. However if all that fails for any reason, IIS should prevent the files being served as static items because the default MIME types don't include `.mdf` & `.ldf`.  But if you still aren't comfortable you could just store these files in the standard SQL data folders.

Comment: @Kev, thank for answering. If I often publish (by right clicking on project node ...) my app to a different web site on the same IIS for testing, what is the easiest way to make the published (production) database get in sync with development database in both direction (changes in development phase must be committed to production, vice versa)? Note: This publishing scenario is just an additional scenario to the scenario I asked in this thread at the very beginning.

Comment: @xport - this is a complex feature and generally costs money :). There's tooling in VS Premium and Ultimate to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193288.aspx. I use RedGate's  SQL Compare (for schema sync) and SQL Data Compare (for data sync).

Comment: OK. I will use the trial version first just for learning purpose. Thank for the link @Kev. I might be back later for getting your help. :-)

Comment: @Kev, Assume I put NerdDinner.mdb in a separate folder outside the physical directory of my site/app. Do I need to grant the application pool identity account (named "iis apppool\NerdDinner") to the folder in which NerdDinner.mdb exists? Or granting setup from within SQL Server Management Studio is more than enough? I am wondering I make unnecessary or redundant granting. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @xport - you don't need to grant access to the SQL database files to the worker process account because it's SQL server that will be touching them.

Comment: @Kev: I want to attach a database using `User Instance = True`. Unless I set `Load User Profile = True`, I will get an error saying `Login failed...`. Is it safe to enable this user profile?

Comment: @recycle - you should be ok with that.

Comment: @Kev: Pertaining to your statement "... grant the requisite permissions to the pool identity on your web folders ...", what will happen if I just grant `write only` permission on the web folder to the application pool identity? So far I have not found any problem.

Comment: @recycle - as in write permissions but not read permissions? Or read/write but not modify?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything *obviously* wrong here - the only things I would perhaps query are:

- Do you really need IIS 6 Metabase
  configuration compatibility here, if,
  as it looks like, you're building a
  server from scratch?
- Rather than your
  database user the having db_owner
  role, could you get away with just
  having db_datareader/db_datawriter? (I don't know the NerdDinner database so it could be totally correct, it's just an observation)

Comment: IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility is needed by Visual Studio to allow me to browse IIS from within Visual Studio. Second, I will try to change from db_owner to a pair of db_datareader & db_datawriter. I will confirm the result soon.

Comment: If this is your development machine then `db_owner` will be fine because you can then do DDL from within Visual Studio. Most shared host production environments will make the first login (which is usually all you get) db_owner anyway because many apps such as DotNetNuke etc need full control over their databases to bootstrap their schemas etc.